# How to check if server is running a method in Java HttpServer; getting java.net.UnknownHostException

Tags: java, networking

I am scheduling tasks on servers but I have no idea how to know if any server is currently doing the task. I am looping over servers like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < tasksList.size(); i++){
    for(URL url : serverURLsList){
        if(InetAddress.getByName(url.toString()).isReachable(0)){ //this gives me exception
           HttpURLConnection availableServer = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
           availableServer.setDoOutput(true);
           ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(availableServer.getOutputStream());
           oos.writeObject(tasksList.get(i));
           oos.close();
           tasksList.remove(i);
           break;
        }
     }
 }
```

This is my server for task handling:

```
public class Serv{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int port = 8080;

        String host = "192.168.1.116"; 



        System.out.println("Server 1 is up. Host: " + host + " port: " + port);
        HttpServer s= HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(host, port), 0);
        s.createContext("/", new RootHandler());
        s.setExecutor(null);
        s.start();
    }

}

class RootHandler implements HttpHandler{

    private static int clientCounter = 1;

    @Override
    public void handle(HttpExchange exchange) throws IOException {

        System.out.println("\nRoot handler; \n\tclient no. " + clientCounter++);

        Task t;
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(exchange.getRequestBody());
        try {
            System.out.println("Recieved object:");
            t = (Task) ois.readObject();
            ois.close();
            System.out.println("Array not sorted:");
            int[] arr = (int[]) t.getData();
            for (int anArr : arr) {
                System.out.print(anArr + " ");
            }
            TaskSolver.solve(t); // need to check if this is runned on the server or server is doing nothing
            System.out.println("\nArray sorted!");
            for (int anArr : (int[])t.getData()) {
                System.out.print(anArr + " ");
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String response = "<h1>Server up!</h1>";
        exchange.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.getBytes().length);
        OutputStream os = exchange.getResponseBody();
        os.write(response.getBytes());
        os.close();
    }
}
```

What I really want to achieve is have the information if any server in the list is currently solving the task (the comment in the snippet above shows that place). No idea why getting the exception mentioned in the title because I can reach the server from the web browser. I suppose the method `isReachable()` is not good for that purpose (because it should tell if the host given is up or not while I want to know if the proper method on the server is currently running). Does somebody know a good solution to do so?

**@Edit**
According to the comment I need to say that each of my servers (I will have plenty of them) should be doing only one task, that is the purpose of my simulation.

Comment: Do you really want single-threaded servers?  Can your server really handle only one task at a time?  Also, you send the response before you have actually done anything with the request... that doesn't seem right.  In order to have the server reply with a "Busy" message to a new request you'll have to have more request processing threads, one that will be busy with a request and additional threads to reply to additional incoming requests with a "Busy" message.

Comment: Yes, I need the single threaded server. This is kind of substitution for that. Instead one server with threads I have many many servers (it is called fog computing). Can you please provide any kind of implementation to help me figure your idea out? Yeah, i know that response is wrong, I forgot to change it (i was testing if I can reach the server from web browser)

Comment: Documentation on how to write a multi-threaded request handler is available all over the web, please do the research.  It's relatively easy but not trivial, and we're not going to write it for you.

Comment: Ok, to sum up then. I need to have two threads in my handler: one for busy state and one for not. But still, I do not know how to check that state in the looping :(

Comment: Each time you get a request you launch a handler thread.  The handler thread checks to see if another task handler thread is already running and replies "Busy" if it finds one, otherwise it handles the task. Doing this correctly and making sure you don't get into race conditions requires some expertise in multi-threaded programming.  Research this (the Java tutorials on threading might be helpful), write the code, test it, and when you run into problems, ask a new question here showing your code.

Answer (score -1):

```
InetAddress.getByName(url.toString()).isReachable(0)){ //this gives me exception
```

Of course it does. The argument to `InetAddress.getByName()` is not a URL. Check the Javadoc. It is a hostname.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the OP's question.

Comment: @JimGarrison I beg your pardon? The OP has posted a piece of code that he clearly states throws an `UnknownHostException`, right there in the *title,* and also in the code itself.

Comment: Please note that this is not the real matter in the question. `isReachable()` method was just an attempt to manage with the actual problem. The title is two-part.

Comment: @soommy12 In that case it is up to the OP to clarify both his title and his question. I have answered the question expressed in the title. Unclear what else can possibly be expected. 'How to check whether a server is running' is at least partly answered by `isReachabe()`, and if the OP is going to continue to use that he is certainly going to have to adopt the solution in this answer.

Comment: @EJP Imo, you still answer only to the half of the question. It was specified that method with exception is wrong and other solutions are sought. Your answer only tackles "why" the exception appears and not how to deal with it. If you want to answer properly to this answer you should at least provide one alternative way to solve the actual problem.